# Objective-C: Code Explanation

Tags: objective-c

I need code explanation for the code below:

```
AutoCompletePlaceType PlaceTypeFromDictionary(NSDictionary *placeDictionary)
{
    return [[placeDictionary objectForKey:@"types"] containsObject:@"establishment"] ? PlaceTypeEstablishment : PlaceTypeGeocode;
}
```

Starting with the first line...

Comment: Perhaps you need a little more than help, then.  Lookup functions (in C), the docs on NSDictionary, and ternary operators, all of which are rudimentary elements of both C and ObjC.

Comment: How about using Google? It shall not hurt, shall it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a relatively straightforward *function*<sup>1</sup> that analyzes an `NSDictionary`, and produces<sup>2</sup> one of two `AutoCompletePlaceType` values:

- `PlaceTypeEstablishment` if the dictionary's element at the key called `@"element"` contains a string object with the value `@"establishment"`, and
- `PlaceTypeGeocode` if there is no element at the key called `@"element"`, or the corresponding collection does not contain the word `@"establishment"` among its values.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a C *function*, not an Objective C *method*.

<sup>2</sup> The decision is made using a [ternary conditional operator `? :`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?:#C).

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply.  Even though AutoCompletePlaceType does not have () parenthesis around it, it still returns a value?  Under what circumstances does return type can be without the parenthesis?  Thanks.

Comment: @user1107173 That's the point I was trying to make in the footnote #1: the `-(AutoCompletePlaceType)placeTypeFromDictionary` would be a method syntax, where parentheses are required around the type name. The function syntax does not have parentheses around the type name. You call it like this: `AutoCompletePlaceType apt = PlaceTypeFromDictionary(someNsDictionary);`